# AutoResolve SVN Conflicts for a properties file

Tags: svn, ant, properties

I have a properties file that has two values that continuously cause conflicts.   I'm trying to figure out how to auto-resolve conflicts in my SVN based on the value.  I want to always accept the higher number for simplicity sake. Here are the values

```
>>>>>>>=.r701
Application.revision=700
Application.buildnumber=5,572
<<<<<<<=.mine
Application.revision=701
Application.buildnumber=5,571
=\=\=\=\=\=\=
```

I would like to load or parse this properties file, then get the higher numbers and auto-select the higher number.   Is there a good way to do this other than parsing the file manually?

Is there a way to use "ant" or "subversion", or just the Java program itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subversion - Always resolve conflicts using mine for a set of files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002135/subversion-always-resolve-conflicts-using-mine-for-a-set-of-files)

Comment: This is the same issue, but I'm looking for a different solution.  That question is using generated code.  I'm trying to figure out how to replace the value in question with the higher of the two numbers.

Comment: I keep looking at it and thinking..   I have CASUALApp.properties, CASUALApp.properties.mine, CASUALApp.properties.r717 and CASUALApp.properties.r720...     If there was some way to loop through all of those properties files and figure out if one has a higher value than another, it would work.

Comment: Go with one of the two solutions offered. Either use the feature of subversion that will favour the latest revision, or avoid conflicts in the first place using the approach suggested by Bimlash. Looping through files just seems too messy to me... Two reasons: it ties your build to subversion and ANT is not a true programming language :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANT has a `ReplaceTask` http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html

You could define your properties like:

```
Application.revision=@rev@
Application.buildnumber=@build@
```

And replace `@rev@` and `@build@` tokens with appropriate values before checking-in. This will not create conflict, but, you will have to read/generate these token values external to the properties file.

Comment: where do they get stored then? The build may be incremented several times during a work cycle.    Several people are working on this project.   There surely must be provisions for monotonic numbers.

Comment: @AdamOutler What is being suggested here is an approach that avoids the need to resolve conflicts in the first place. Provide transient data like application version and build number as parameters to your build (managed by a build server like Jenkins). This is very easy to do in ANT using the command-line "-D" parameters. Much simpler and more standard solution. Personally I just declare these variables at the top of my build.xml file with default values, secure in the knowledge that I will over-ride them at build time.